# ConditionalPanel around menuItem Doesn't Display Properly

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How would you wrap a `menuitem` in a conditional panel such that it looks like the rest of the menu items?

Try clicking on B and see how the C menu item looks as compared to menu items A or B -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
      menuItem("A", tabName = "a",  icon = icon("group", lib="font-awesome")),
      menuItem("B", tabName = "b", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome")),
      conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'b'",
        sliderInput("b", "Under sidebarMenu", 1, 100, 50)
      ),
      conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'b'",
        menuItem("C", tabName = "c", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome"))
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

(Most of the code borrowed from - https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/28)

I'd like the solution to not need tinkering around with the CSS or some other background setting.

Comment: wrap it inside a `sidebarMenu( )` ?

Comment: `sidebarMenu(conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'b'",
        menuItem("C", tabName = "c", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome"))
      ))` ? Doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant just the `menuItem()` - `sidebarMenu(menuItem(...))`

Comment: `menuItem(conditionalPanel...))`? Doesn't work either.

Comment: `conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'b'",
                                 sidebarMenu( menuItem("C", tabName = "c", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome")) )
                )`

Comment: Don't understand why it works but it does :). Would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution that works is to wrap the `menuItem` inside a `sidebarMenu( )` again

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
                menuItem("A", tabName = "a",  icon = icon("group", lib="font-awesome")),
                menuItem("B", tabName = "b", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome")),
                conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'b'",
                                 sliderInput("b", "Under sidebarMenu", 1, 100, 50)
                ),
                conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'b'",
                                 sidebarMenu(menuItem("C", tabName = "c", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome")))
                )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, after doing a bit of research I can't see **why** this is necessary (am wondering if it's related to [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/86) in some way?

If someone has a detailed explanation I'd be grateful to hear it :)

Comment: I assume `conditionalPanel` is calculated after everything is displayed. Therefore the `menuItem` will be missing some CSS tags. `sidebarMenu` adds those extra tags to the `menuItem` element and it becomes ok.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in the solution by @tospig, the highlighting of the active menu item does not work well. I found this works without any problems:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu == 'b'",
        sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
            menuItem("A", tabName = "a",  icon = icon("group", lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("B", tabName = "b", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome")),
            sliderInput("b", "Under sidebarMenu", 1, 100, 50)
            menuItem("C", tabName = "c", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome"))
        )
    ),
    conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu != 'b'",
        sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
            menuItem("A", tabName = "a",  icon = icon("group", lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("B", tabName = "b", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome"))
        )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```